# List of combinations from a list of values?

Tags: haskell, combinations, cartesian-product

How can I obtain a list of combinations from a list of lists?

For example:

```
ghci> getCombinations [[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[100,200,300]]

[[1,10,100],[1,10,200],[1,10,300],[1,20,100],[1,20,200],[1,20,300],[1,30,100],
[1,30,200],[1,30,300],[2,10,100],[2,10,200],[2,10,300],[2,20,100],[2,20,200],
[2,20,300],[2,30,100],[2,30,200],[2,30,300],[3,10,100],[3,10,200],[3,10,300],
[3,20,100],[3,20,200],[3,20,300],[3,30,100],[3,30,200],[3,30,300]]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate n-ary Cartesian Product](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387359/calculate-n-ary-cartesian-product)

Answer (score 2):

```
import Control.Applicative

getCombinations :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
getCombinations values =
foldl (\acc values -> (\list value -> list ++ [value]) <$> acc <*> values) [[]] values

getCombinations [[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[100,200,300]]
```

[[1,10,100],[1,10,200],[1,10,300],[1,20,100],[1,20,200],[1,20,300],[1,30,100],[1,30,200],[1,30,300],[2,10,100],[2,10,200],[2,10,300],[2,20,100],[2,20,200],[2,20,300],[2,30,100],[2,30,200],[2,30,300],[3,10,100],[3,10,200],[3,10,300],[3,20,100],[3,20,200],[3,20,300],[3,30,100],[3,30,200],[3,30,300]]

Comment: The simpler version, without the need for an `import`, is `sequence`.

Comment: LOL! You are right:

sequence [[1,2,3],[10,20,30],[100,200,300]]