# Clean list comprehension for sampling from list of lists?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I have a lists of list in Haskell. I want to get all the possibilities when taking one element from each list. What I have currently is

```
a = [ [1,2], [10,20,30], [-1,-2] ] -- as an example
whatIWant = [ [p,q,r] | p <- a!!0, q <- a!!1, r <- a!!2 ]
```

This does what I want. However, this is obviously not very good code, and I'm looking for a better way of writing the list comprehension so that no index number (0,1,2) shows up in the code... which is where I'm stuck.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you insist on doing it using a list comprehension? I think for such a kind of task a function is better and cleaner.

Comment: @JanŽegklitz Thanks for the comment. It isn't that I insist on that: I just felt there'd be a good and clean way of writing it with a list comprehension, and didn't know at all if that's possible or not.

Comment: You want the cartesian product of all the lists. Use `sequence a` to achieve that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387359/calculate-n-ary-cartesian-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this is obviously not a good code

This is about the best way you can do it, given your constraint that the input is a list of lists.

If you use a different type, e.g. a triple of lists, then you can index structurally. E.g.

```
Prelude> let x@(a,b,c) = ( [1,2],  [10,20,30], [-1,-2] )
```

Lets you write:

```
Prelude> [ (p,q,r) | p <- a , q <- b , r <- c ]
[(1,10,-1),(1,10,-2),(1,20,-1)
,(1,20,-2),(1,30,-1),(1,30,-2)
,(2,10,-1),(2,10,-2),(2,20,-1)
,(2,20,-2),(2,30,-1),(2,30,-2)]
```

Lesson: to avoid indexing, use a type whose structure captures the invariant you want to hold. Lift the dimension of the data into its type.

Comment: What if I had to handle large list `(x@(a,b,c, ....,z, za..))`? Should I seek for a function as @JanŽegklitz suggested?  // I only knew `@` in the context of pattern matching, and it's great to know.

Answer (score 2):

Using a function (which uses a list comprehension inside), my solution is

```hs
combinations :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
combinations [] = []
combinations [l] = map (\ x -> [x]) l
combinations (x:xs) = combine (combinations [x]) (combinations xs)
    where combine a b = [ p ++ q | p <- a, q <- b ]
```

Example:

```hs
*Main> combinations [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
[[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6],[3,4],[3,5],[3,6]]
*Main> combinations [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2']]
["aA1","aA2","aB1","aB2","aC1","aC2","bA1","bA2","bB1",...
 "bB2","bC1","bC2","cA1","cA2","cB1","cB2","cC1","cC2"]
```

---

Edit: of course you can use the `sequence` function, as was suggested in the comments:

```hs
*Main> sequence [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['1', '2']]
["aA1","aA2","aB1","aB2","aC1","aC2","bA1","bA2","bB1",...
 "bB2","bC1","bC2","cA1","cA2","cB1","cB2","cC1","cC2"]
```